# PHP Session issue only on GoDaddy (Warning: session_start(): Cannot send session cookie)

Tags: php, mysql, session, cookies

I am currently working on a user registration system for a client on GoDaddy hosting.

I have previously never had this sort of issue before on Hostgator and while testing locally on a PHP test server on OS X.

It's a fairly simple script too. common.php accesses the MySQL database, all of the pages (login, register, etc.) include common.php. Sessions start when the user logs in, etc.

I see the following errors at the top of the page:

> Warning: session_start(): open(/home/content/10/12114910/tmp/sess_trmok9fgtb527mjp21a76shf54, O_RDWR) failed: No such file or directory (2) in /home/content/10/12114910/html/common.php on line 86
>
> Warning: session_start(): Cannot send session cookie - headers already sent by (output started at /home/content/10/12114910/html/common.php:86) in /home/content/10/12114910/html/common.php on line 86
>
> Warning: session_start(): Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at /home/content/10/12114910/html/common.php:86) in /home/content/10/12114910/html/common.php on line 86

The following errors are at the bottom of the page.

> Warning: Unknown: open(/home/content/10/12114910/tmp/sess_trmok9fgtb527mjp21a76shf54, O_RDWR) failed: No such file or directory (2) in Unknown on line 0
>
> Warning: Unknown: Failed to write session data (files). Please verify that the current setting of session.save_path is correct () in Unknown on line 0

Once again, this is only a GoDaddy issue. My client was originally on Windows hosting and this just did not even work at all and I switched them to Linux hosting.

They were on PHP version 5.3 and I changed it to 5.4 and I have still had no luck.

I have never messed with a php.ini file. Would I need to create one? I have heard that uploading it into the public_html folder overrides the one on the server even though we are on a shared hosting plan.

Would I also need SSH access to create a tmp folder and set proper permissions for it?

Comment: where is your code bro

Comment: What do you get if you do `var_dump(session_save_path())`? Does your application have write permissions on the filepath indicated?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is usually quite easy to fix on crappy providers (I don't recommend GoDaddy, by the way).

Here is how I'd go about fixing it, hopefully it will help you.

> Step 1: Make a directory and call it `_sessions` or something of that
>   nature.
>
> Step 2: Give it a chmod of 775 so that the web server can write to it.
>
> Step 3: On the first script that runs, right at the top place `session_save_path("./_sessions");`
>
> Step 4 (optional, but recommended): Add either `deny from all` in a .htaccess file to prevent people from getting to the directory, or simply chmod 776.

Find out more about `session_save_path()` here: [php.net/session_save_path](http://php.net/session_save_path)

Comment: Thank you very much! I am going to advise my client to get off of GoDaddy. You got back to me before their support did and I am extremely grateful for that.

Comment: @AndrewMRiv I've improved my answer with a little tip for you, see step 4.